# How to store related model data on through model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a :through relationship between 2 models because I have extra data I want to store in the join table -- otherwise I would just use the :source relationship.

But the data I want to store is dynamic -- it's a list of questions that have been added to an instance of one of the models I am joining.  Example:

Physicians add unique questions that patients should answer when making an appointment -- Dr. Foo wants his patients to answer 'height' and 'weight', while Dr. Bar wants his patents to answer 'age' and 'gender'.

What is the cleanest way to store the answers to these questions in the Appointment model instance?

current Models:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
end

class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

Thanks in advance -- I have come across this several times and would love to hear a good answer on it -- another example is: User takes a Quiz.  Quiz has_many Questions.
How would you store the unique answers to the static set of questions each Quiz has?  Again, I'm stuck at using a :through relationship using a join table called Attempts.

Possible solution I thought of: Patient has_many Surveys and Survey has_many Answers. Create this when a new Appointment is made. Problem is, I'm finding the views and controllers to be quite complex for something as simple as, to restate my question, store data related to a joining table.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recomend adding a new model called `Answer` for storing this information. Something like

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: appointment
  belongs_to: patient
end
```

The relationship with the `Question` model could be difficult to maintain. Think of a question that has already been ananswered and changes its text from 'how old are you?' to 'when did you born?'. You'll have to prevent this change at the question model or store the question text with the answer and forgot the relationship.

Another option would be to use a serialized atribute on the appointment model to store its questions and answers.

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient

  serialize :answers
end
```

You'll need to add a text attribute to the appointment table called `answers`

The answers attribute will be a hash where you can save something like `{question_text_1: answer_1, question_text_2: answer_2}`. This will allow you to easily use it on the view.

It's also easy to write the method to save/update this attribute allowing an easy form on the corresponding view.

Again, it's necesary to define what will happen to old appointments when a physician changes  question titles.

Comment: How about adding belongs_to question too in Answer model. and then fire query patient.answers.where(question_id in (physician.questions.pluck(:id) and appointment_id = appointmentId)... The serialize suggestion is cooler I feel. Would be less expensive at query firing and overall complexity

Comment: question & answer relationship is clear but too academic: what happens if you want to change a question text but it has several answers already linked? Should you invalidate old answers or prevent question edits? Regarding serialization, it's my preferred option as long as it doesn't require too much logic like answer validation or complex callbacks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need two extra tables here: Answer, and AppointmentQuestion. There is the tricky issue of the questions_to_ask, the questions_answered and answers. I've addressed the questions_to_ask by delegating from the appointment to the physician, giving Appointment.physician_questions. The idea is the appointment will know what questions to ask, and will store the questions answered

I got to this solution by drawing entiry relationship diagrams and then looking at creating intermediate object where m-m relationships exist. The stuff below isn't complete.

This suggests a general solution of having a table that contains a row for each time the question is asked (perhaps rename AppointmentQuestion to AskedQuestion)

```
AppointmentQuestion
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :appointemnt
  has_one :answer

Answer
  belongs_to :AppointmentQuestion

Appointment
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
  has_many questions through appointment_question
  has_many answers through appointment_question
  delegate :questions, to: :doctor, prefix: true

Patient
  has_many appointments

Physician
  has_many appointments
  has_many questions

Question
  belongs_to physician
  has_may answers through appointment_question
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which database you are using but to me that looks like the perfect example for using Postgres HStore. Considering your data is dynamic, unstructured.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html

You could have a field questions of the type hstore

On your appointment migration

```
def change
  create_table :named_searches do |t|
    t.hstore questions
  end
end
```

And you would have that field available on your models (it works like a hash with key value pairs, questions and answers in your case)

When you query for questions on that case, you will get a list of questions with their respective answers, and although the list is dynamic (any question can be added/the appointments don't need to have the same questions), it can be saved to the database seamlessly